# $c= (a^{x}-b^{x})$ where $a$,$b$ and $c$ are known real constants. Solve for $x$.

Tags: logarithms

I tried taking $\log$ on both side but i ended with $\log(a^{x}-b^{x})$ which is difficult to solve. Does anybody has idea how to solve the above equation for $x$.

Comment: i think there is no chance to solve this equation for $x$ (with elementary operations)

Comment: What are $a,b,c$? (rational, real, complex?)

Comment: Care to elaborate on that, @Dr.SonnhardGraubner?

Comment: Except for very few specific cases, there is no analytical solutions and only numerical methods would apply.

Comment: Does the Lambert W function apply here?

Comment: Similar: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1584078/how-to-simplify-a-sum-of-exponential-equation/1585685#1585685

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Could you explain why there are no analytical solutions, or at least provide a reference?

Comment: @A.P. Don't you think that Simple Art gave the answer writing $0=x^n+ax+c$ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici No, I don't. I'm fully aware of the Abel–Ruffini theorem: it only tells us that it is unlikely that we can find an *algebraic* solution to $x^n + ax + c = 0$, but it doesn't say anything about *analytic* solutions. For example, it seems that [quintic equations can be solved analytically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_function#Beyond_radicals) (though I don't know the details). Furthermore, I don't know anything about equations of the form $x^\alpha + ax +c = 0$ with $\alpha$ real non-integer, which may or may not be easier to solve.

Comment: @A.P. I am sorry to be unable to argue; I am not a mathematician in the real sense of the word. It seems clear that for a few specific values of $\alpha$, the equation reduces to a trivial polynomial with (eventually) explicit solutions. But, for th general case, I don't see anything else numerical methods. Sorry for that; Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

I could try to simplify it a little:$$c=a^x-b^x=a^x-a^{x\log_a(b)}$$$$a^x=u$$$$c=u-u^{\log_a(b)}$$$$0=u^{\log_a(b)}-u+c$$From here, you might notice that we can't solve for $u$ because we can't solve the following general problem:$$0=x^n+ax+c$$If we could solve the above problem for any $n$, then we'd probably have things like algebraic solutions to quintic polynomials and such.

In fact, we pretty much can only solve this if:$$0\le n\le4$$And if $n$ is an integer.

We see that $\log_b(a)$ will most likely not be an integer and it will most likely not be between $4,0$.

Comment: Sorry to disappoint you.